# What are the existing theories or methodologies around synchronizing tree structures?

Tags: data-structures, synchronization

I need to compare and synchronize two tree data structures.

I have Tree A (the "Reference Tree") and Tree B (the "Target Tree"). I need to bring the Target Tree into compliance with the Reference Tree. I need to find differences -- additions and deletions, including those that result in new descendants or branches -- and bring the trees into synchronization.

I have to assume there is a body of thought/knowledge around this, given all the JavaScript DOM-based templating/UI systems out there (note: I'm *not* working in JS, that's just a handy example).

What names/theories am I looking for here? I'm not asking for actual instruction, I just want to know what schools of thought or practice exist that I should start with, rather from fumbling around from scratch.

Comment: Just one thought, if you are trying to implement some sort of replication, a much easier approach might be to keep track of the changes directly instead of trying to guess at them based on the starting state and ending state.

Comment: You mean, like a database's transaction log? Record them from the Reference Tree and "replay" them on the Target Tree?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.  You haven't given much info on the use case so I'm not sure it's even relevant.

Comment: No, it's a good thought. Thank you. It's got my gears turning.

Comment: The trick there is making sure you have every change in order.  You might want to at least do a comparison to verify that things haven't diverged.  You'll want something for testing/regression purposes.

Comment: I actually do have a comprehensive audit/transaction log, totally independent of this current issue. So, it's not out of the question.

Answer (score 6):

The main challenge/consideration when doing this is determining what you consider a difference to be.  This can be more tricky than you might think.  The experience I had that lead me to that conclusion was around XML which has thankfully fallen into disuse, at least for new development.  Finding a good XML diffing tool was tough.  It might be a place to start your research, though.

Probably the main thing is to determine whether ordering of child nodes matters.  For example, are the following trees the same or different?

```
A   A
|\  |\
B C C B
```

Aside from that and what properties you are considering, the approach to determining differences is pretty straightforward: recursion.  A node is the same if it has all the same children and they are the same.

Where things get tricky again is how you interpret those differences.  For example:

```
A    A 
|\   |    
B C  D    
     |\  
     B C
```

I can interpret that at least 2 different ways.  The first being that a new node `D` was inserted.  The other being that `B` and `C` were deleted, `D` was added, and `B` and `C` were added to `D`.  The latter interpretation is easier, in my estimation, to code.  The former will require you to come up with more rules.  One last example:

```
A   A
|\  |
B C D
    |
    B
```

Now if you want to see that as `D` being inserted and `C` being deleted (again, does order matter?), you need to make a lot of assumptions.  Ultimately, it comes down to the fact that there are many different transformations that result in the same tree structure.  To a large degree, what you should infer from a given before and after image will depend on the way they will be synchronized.

Answer (score 4):

Let me show you an old requirements trick:

> I need to compare and synchronize two tree data structures.
>
> I have Tree A (the "Reference Tree") and Tree B (the "Target Tree"). I need to bring the Target Tree into compliance with the Reference Tree. I need to find differences -- additions and deletions, including those that result in new descendants or branches -- and bring the trees into synchronization.

I challenge these requirements. I believe they are under specified. As proof, consider a proposed solution: Discard the old B. Make a copy of Tree A and name it B.

I'm sure you have reasons this wont work. But since you didn't tell us what those are this is what you get from me until you do.

Comment: This is a very good trick. There are many practical reasons why I can't do this, but your point is taken (and upvoted).

Comment: @Deane well thank you for the up vote. But you were supposed to tell me the hidden requirements that keep this from being a viable solution.

Comment: The Target Tree might have changes that need to persist, regardless of the Reference Tree. I should have mentioned that above, but to be fair, I was just asking for referrals to theories on tree synchronization. I wasn't actually asking for people to solve the specific problem (though I'm very grateful), hence the lack of detailed requirements.

Comment: @Deane np. But understand, there is a lot of research to refer you to. It can help to know what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic problem is not difficult to solve, and doesn't support a "school of thought" of its own - you'd just be looking for something like "algorithms on tree structures".

As to an algorithm, you start at the root, moving breadth first, compare the node, and alter the target (and any descendants) if they do not match. Typically this algorithm will use recursion.

And compare (and alter) the ordering at each level, if ordering is important.

I suspect things in this area only get complicated when there are specific nuances of an application, that aren't implied by the general problem. If that's the case, you may wish to be more specific about the context of your problem.

For example, if you distinguish structural changes from content changes - in other words, if the replacement of a node (and the relations it has with other nodes) is distinct from the replacement of its contents - then you might find that such cases cannot be distinguished from a mere comparison of the contents of each node. The solution in this situation is that you would have to store additional data that represents the unique identity of the node.